# Why is even codimension necessary to apply excision for the Euler characteristic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71960), it is claimed that 
$$\chi(X\setminus Z)=\chi(X)-\chi(Z)$$
holds for complex subvarieties $Z$ only because $Z$ has even codimension. It is implied that for $Z$ with odd codimension, this may fail. Why is this? Is this point discussed in some standard reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a simple counterexample, take $X=S^1$ and $Z$ to be a point.  Then $\chi(X\setminus Z)=1\neq \chi(X)-\chi(Z)=-1$.  Morally, what's going wrong here is that you should consider $\chi(X\setminus Z)$ to be $-1$ rather than $1$, since it is made up of only a single (open) $1$-cell and no other cells.  But if you take the standard homological definition of Euler characteristic, you get $1$, not $-1$.

So, why does $\chi(X\setminus Z)=\chi(X)-\chi(Z)$ if $Z$ has even codimension, at least in nice cases?  Well, if $Z$ sits in $X$ nicely enough, then it has a tubular neighborhood $T\cong Z\times \mathbb{R}^d$ (where $d$ is even).   Then Mayer-Vietoris tells us $\chi(X)=\chi(T)+\chi(X\setminus Z)-\chi(T\cap(X\setminus Z))$.  We have $\chi(T)=\chi(Z)$ since $T$ deformation-retracts to $Z$ and $T\cap(X\setminus Z)\cong (\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus\{0\})\times Z$ so $\chi(T\cap(X\setminus Z))=\chi((\mathbb{R}^{d}\setminus\{0\})\chi(Z)=0$ since $d$ is even (if $d$ were odd, the first factor would be $2$ instead of $0$).  Thus $\chi(X)=\chi(Z)+\chi(X\setminus Z)$, which is what we wanted.  In the odd codimension case, the problem is that the homological Euler characteristic of the open set $\chi(X\setminus Z)$ is "wrong" because it treats odd-dimensional open cells as if they could be contracted to a point (which makes them count as $1$ rather than $-1$ towards the Euler characteristic), as in the counterexample discussed above.

Comment: Is it possible to create a tubular neighborhood when Z is singular, but still of even codimension? Then it seems the usual construction in terms of the normal bundle breaks down. And it seems this case is needed for the answer I linked.

Comment: @user4571: Hrm, I guess not in general (think about if $X$ is a singular curve and $Z$ is a node of $X$).  And in fact, in the case of a node on a curve the identity $\chi(X)=\chi(Z)+\chi(X\setminus Z)$ is not true.

Comment: If $X$ is a complete rational curve with a single node, then $\chi(X)=\chi(X\setminus Z)=1$ so the left-hand side is $1$ and the right-hand side is $2$.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps too much to ask, but is there a counter example when the ambient space is smooth but the divisor is singular, or can a tubular neighborhood argument still work?

Comment: The tubular neighborhood argument doesn't work (if $Z$ is singular, then $Z\times\mathbb{R}^d$ is singular and so can't be an open set in a smooth ambient space).  But if $X$ is smooth and $Z$ is compact, you can instead make a Poincare duality argument to get that $\chi(X)=\chi(Z)+\chi(X-Z)$ as long as $X$ is even-dimensional.  See Theorem 3.44 of [Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html), for instance.

Comment: Note that this argument doesn't even require $Z$ to have even codimension. This maybe shouldn't be so surprising, because when everything is smooth, $Z$ is compact, and $X$ is even-dimensional, then the tubular neighborhood argument still works even if $Z$ has odd codimension, since in that case $\chi(Z)=0$ (since $Z$ is a closed odd-dimensional manifold) so $\chi(T\cap(X\setminus Z))=0$ still even though $\chi(\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\})=2$.